# android how to add same fragments with different activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Activity A

```
  SectionPagerAdapter pageradapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                pageradapter.addFragment(ContactsFragment.newInstance(), "PHONE CONTACTS");
                pageradapter.addFragment(CustomersFragment.newInstance(), "CUSTOMERS");
               viewPager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
```

Activity B

```
 SectionPagerAdapter pageradapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    pageradapter.addFragment(ContactsFragment.newInstance(), "PHONE CONTACTS");
                    pageradapter.addFragment(CustomersFragment.newInstance(), "CUSTOMERS");
                   viewPager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
```

I am using fragments and viewpager in my android application.In activity A i have added one fragment with viewpager it is working fine.Now the issue is i want to use the same fragment in Activity B also.

Note: when i add the same fragment in viewpager its throwing error like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: app.com.Contacts.ContactsActivity cannot be cast to app.com.Contacts.Activity.CustomersActivity
```

Comment: can you make it more clear , how do you add same fragment to different viewpager if you're calling newInstance(), two code snippets you shared are identical , what is the point

Comment: no i am asking is it possible to use same fragment for different activities

Comment: yes reusability is the reason why fragments exists

Comment: can you please provide some code snippet

Comment: in what context am i supposed to provide code , i don't know what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fragment`'s code you cast the activity to `ContactsActivity`. This is why you can not reuse it. So, you have to remove this cast from your `Fragment`'s code.

If you would like to call an `Activity` function which the `Fragment` is attached. You can do it with interfaces. If your activities implements the same interface. It is enough to cast the `Activity` to the interface in your `Fragment`'s code.

```
class FragmentA {
   private void myMehod() {
      ((MyInterface)getActivity()).callMethodOnActivity()
   }
}
```